# How do I convert SPUser to SPFieldUser?

Tags: column, spfield, spuser, spfielduser

I have a field in a list that accepts an SPFieldUser object. I have an SPUser object that I would like to populate that field with, but I cannot implicitly convert from one to the other.

How would I do this conversion?

Comment: Whenever i use this code it shows me an error such as "Nullreferenceexception was unhandled by the user code". Any Ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It sounds like you've gotten two concepts slightly muddled. There are three entities that are important here:

- A field/column on a list ([SPField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.aspx) and its derivatives, including [SPFieldUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.aspx))
- A row of data ([SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx))
- A data item (string, [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx), etc. according to field type)

Each row of data (List Item) has a data item for each of the fields, but fields themselves do not accept any data; they determine what the data is and how to handle it.

So in order to add an [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx) to a [SPFieldUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.aspx) you would have to instead add it to the relevant List Item. For example:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.List;
SPListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(1);
listItem["Author"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
listItem.Update();
```

When the data item is set in the code above, the [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx) object is converted into a [SPFieldUserValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservalue.aspx) in the background. [SPFieldUserValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservalue.aspx) is just a wrapper around the [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx) class that the [SPFieldUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.aspx) uses to save and handle it.

Unfortunately we can't take advantage of that automatic conversion when we get the value back out, so we have to do the following:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.List;
SPListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(1);

SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web, listItem["Author"].ToString());
SPUser user = userValue.User;
```

Comment: I went on to write about this and more (lookups and multiple values) in my blog, but I won't clutter this answer with more (slightly irrelevant) information: http://tsstsst.com/?p=44

Comment: Updated link: http://tsstsst.com/2011/08/16/easily-accessing-lookup-and-user-fields/

Answer (score 5):

You can assign the SPUser object directly to the field:

```
SPUser user = web.SiteUsers["domain\\username"];
item["MyCustomField"] = user;
```

Answer (score 3):

Gets the user that is associated with the field value.

```
SPFieldUserValue userValue=someValue;
SPUser user = userValue.User;
```