# Sharepoint Online JavaScript convert from SPUser to SPFieldUser and get name

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spuser, spfielduser

How can I get full name from SPUser? I got him from get_currentUser() from web context.
And how can I convert from SPUser to SPFieldUser in JS?

EDIT:
I need it to compare, I get from list field SPFieldUser and want to compare it with current user. Or by full name or by domain login (which is better i think). But I cant get both. get_loginName() from web current user doesnt work but . But I get email by _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName or user by userDisplayName. From list I got full user name by get_lookupValue() but cant get login name. But I wish to compare it by domain login or email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve current user's display name, id & login name from _spPageContextInfo object.

```
window.console && console.log('Display Name: ' + _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName);
window.console && console.log('Login Name: ' + _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName);
window.console && console.log('User Id: ' + _spPageContextInfo.userId);
```

To set the list item's user field value

```
var userFld = new SP.FieldUserValue();
userFld.set_lookupId(_spPageContextInfo.userId);

//...
//...
// Set the list item 
item.set_item(person_field_column_Name, userFld);
//...
```

Comment: Thanks, it work! :) Now have to get from list field a login/mail (think its better than compare by full user name).

Comment: userId  and lookupId for list item was enough to compare :) I think it works fine. Without domain login /email/full user name, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use below method to get all the required information of user...

```
function getCurrentUserEmail(){
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  this.website = clientContext.get_web();
  this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
  clientContext.load(currentUser);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestFail));
}
function onRequestSuccess(sender, args){
  var curUserEmail = currentUser.get_email();
  var curUserloginName = currentUser.get_loginName();
  getUserInfo(curUserloginName);
}
function onRequestFail(sender, args){
  alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
function getUserInfo(loginName){
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var userInfoList = context.get_web().get_siteUserInfoList();
  var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
  var viewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>" + loginName+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
  query.set_viewXml(viewXml);
  var items = userInfoList.getItems(query);
  context.load(items,'Include(Deleted,Department,EMail,FirstName,ID,IsActive,IsSiteAdmin,JobTitle,LastName,MobilePhone,Name,Notes,Office,Picture,SipAddress,UserName,WebSite,WorkPhone)');
  context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    if(items.get_count() > 0) {
      var item = items.itemAt(0);
      console.log('User Id: ' + item.ID);
      console.log('First Name: ' + item.FirstName);
      console.log('Last Name: ' + item.LastName);
      console.log('EMail: ' + item.EMail);
      console.log('Name: ' + item.Name);
      console.log('User Name: ' + item.UserName);
    }
  },
    console.log(args.get_message());
  );
```

Comment: I try it, get error when using get_loginName(), uncaught error that it wasnt initiated. I need only loginname or full user name.

Comment: Can you paste your code here, it seems you are trying to use object before it is loaded(executequery has ran)...

Comment: I have in method all this executequery... and this method return item to me but I cant use these function. 
function getUser() {
        var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
        currentUser.retrieve();
        clientContext.load(currentUser);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () { // code to execute if success
            },
            function () { onQueryFailed(); });

        return currentUser;
    }
So this is why this function dont work on my. Now I know and solved problem in other way :) thx anyway

Comment: np....please mark it as answer so that it is helpful to others also...!!

Answer (score 0):

use `get_title()` to get the full name:

```
var usertxt = web.get_currentUser();
usertxt.get_title();
```

why do you want to convert an `SPUser` to an `SPFieldUser`?

this will explain why I ask the question above, if its to update a list item just use the spuser object

[How do I convert SPUser to SPFieldUser?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/how-do-i-convert-spuser-to-spfielduser)